# How can I put a int varriable in system() function of C++

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

I just want to put int variable in system function.How can I do so?
I had written the code below.

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    char str[25];
    cout << "Enter the name of folder:";
    gets(str);
    system("mkdir c:\TURBOC3\BIN:%s", str);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: C++ and C are two different languages. Pick one.

Comment: Use `sprintf`. And turboc jeezzz...

Comment: `system` only takes [a single argument](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/system). Besides that, your `mkdir` argument is wrong (at several points).

Comment: You probably want `sprintf`. But as @SamVarshavchik says, that's a C way of doing things. In C++ you'd probably use a `stringstream`.

Comment: Even simple `std::string` should be enough.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be trying to put a string variable in a system call. `system` only takes one argument of type const char*.

What you can do is use `sprintf` to write the command you want to a char buffer, and then use that char buffer as a parameter to the `system` call.

```
char str[25], command[128];
cout << "Enter the name of the folder:";
gets(str);
sprintf(command,"mkdir c:\TURBOC3\BIN:%s",str);
system(command);
getch();
```

Hope this helped, good luck :)